# How to create a map from list with java-streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to create a Map of a List with java8.

```
class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
    //etc
}

List<Person> persons;

Map<String, Person> personsByName = persons.stream().collect(
         Collectors.toMap(Person::getName, Functions.identify());
```

Result: `The type Person does not define getName(T) that is applicable here`

Why? What is wrong with `Person::getName`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a `getName()` method in `Person`, this should be fine:

```
Map<String, Person> personsByName = persons.stream().collect(
                 Collectors.toMap(Person::getName, Function.identity()));
```

Note that I've also changed `Functions.identify()` (which doesn't exist) with `Function.identity()`. I would assume it was a typo of yours.

Comment: Indeed it was *not* a type, but I used the wrong import (`com.google.common.base.Functions`). Your solution works.